# SQL - Finding if a single value meets criteria from one column

Tags: sql, select, join

I have these two groups of data

```
CNU       RENT       NBED   CATEGORY
--- ---------- ---------- ----------
101        200          2          3
102        220          3          3
103        180          2          2
104        120          1          1
105        300          3          4
106        350          3          4
107        360          3          4
108        400          4          4
109        500          3          5
110        600          4          5



AID EID CNU SID ADATE          HOURS
--- --- --- --- --------- ----------
a01 e08 101 s02 15-MAY-14          3
a02 e03 101 s03 16-MAY-14          4
a03 e02 102 s02 17-MAY-14          2
a04 e09 103 s01 14-MAY-14          3
a05 e06 105 s05 18-MAY-14          5
a06 e06 107 s04 15-MAY-14          3
a07 e03 108 s04 18-MAY-14          4
a08 e09 109 s01 20-MAY-14          5
a09 e08 106 s06 15-MAY-14          3
a10 e10 102 s04 15-MAY-14          2
a11 e02 110 s04 15-MAY-14          4
a12 e10 103 s05 15-MAY-14          5
a13 e05 105 s04 16-MAY-14          4
a14 e10 107 s04 17-MAY-14          3
a15 e09 110 s01 18-MAY-14          3
```

I want to be able to display the EID of those whom are category 3 AND 4.

so the output would look like this

```
EID
---
e03
e08
e10
e02
```

This is the code i have used so far

```
SELECT EID 
FROM Assignment15
JOIN Cottage15
ON Assignment15.Cnum = Cottage15.Cnum
WHERE Category=3  
AND EXISTS (SELECT Category
            FROM Cottage15
            WHERE Category=Cottage15.Category
            AND Category=4);
```

and the result gives me one extra EID

```
EID
---
e03
e08
e10
e02
```

e02 being the extra. I'm not sure what can be adjusted, But it would be a great ton of help if i could get a code that works for this. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `IN` keyword :

```
SELECT EID 
 FROM Assignment15
 JOIN Cottage15 ON Assignment15.Cnum = Cottage15.Cnum
 WHERE Category IN (3,4) 
 GROUP BY EID
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Category) = 2
```

Note that on some DBMS you can also use the `USING` keyword on the `JOIN` condition which would result in

```
SELECT EID 
 FROM Assignment15
 JOIN Cottage15 ON USING(Cnum)
 WHERE Category IN (3,4) 
 GROUP BY EID
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Category) = 2
```

Comment: the IN Keyword outputs all of those that have category 3 or 4.

Comment: @Jay I misunderstood your request at first, edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this using aggregation and `having`:

```
select a.eid
from Assignment15 a join
     Cottage15 c
     on a.Cnum = c.Cnum
where c.Category in (3, 4)
group by a.eid
having count(distinct c.category) = 2 ;
```